# list files in specific directories older than 1 day or 24 hours

Tags: linux, shell, search, find

I am trying to write a simple back up script in python where I try to list the files that are 24 hours old in specific directories that I would choose.

I read the manual of find and used

find .  -mtime 1 > log.dat

to get the list of files in the log.dat however I also get the path information in that list as such

./hpc06MatlabCodes/2011/Apr/3dBoxModel
./hpc06MatlabCodes/2011/Apr/3dBoxModel/vfluidIrca10.dat
./hpc06MatlabCodes/2011/Apr/3dBoxModel/vLRecoveredSystem.mat

is there a way to exclude the directories and only get the files list.
Greetz,
Umut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the '-type f' flag to find:

```
$ find . -type f -a -mtime 1 > log.dat
```

(the `-a` is 'and' - it's the default conjunction but I like to specify it in case the default changes at some point in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing this is python, I would use:

```
def get_old_files(topdir, howold=24*3600):
    import os, time
    now = time.time()
    filelist = []
    def traverse_links(filename):
        if not os.path.islink(filename):
            return filename
        return traverse_links(os.path.normpath(
                    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), os.readlink(filename)))))
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
        for name in [traverse_links(os.path.join(dirpath, f)) for f in filenames]:
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(name) and now - os.path.getmtime(name) > howold:
                    filelist.append(name)
            except OSError:
                pass # ignore bad symlinks
    return filelist
```

This should do what you wish, you could also add an optional argument that will curtail directories.  The advantage of using this over calling `find` is the extra overhead involved with spawning a new process as opposed to doing it all inside the process.

Comment: Thx for the script